# Reading, modifying and writing xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying to read an xml file, update a value and then write the result.

The xml in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM config.dtd">
<config>

    <module name="this">

        <param name="importLabel" value="naksnadksnkas" />

    </module>


</config>
```

Reading and manipulating a value

```
tree = et.parse("path/file.xml")

root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    for sub in child:
        if sub.tag == "param":
            if sub.attrib['name'] == "importLabel":
                sub.attrib['value'] == "working"

tree.write(open('output.xml', 'wb'))
```

However, this returns `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'write'`

I can successfully write the `tree` to file, but this does not capture the updated record which I edited.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Your error however suggests that you are calling the write method on an XML element instead of the tree itself.

Comment: Thanks @wasmachien. When I write the tree itself, I don't see the updated value (I see what was originally loaded via `parse`), how do I update the XML element within this tree?

Comment: Try this:import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
´´´
tree = et.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall("module/param"):
    child.attrib["a"] = "b"

tree.write("output.xml")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall("module/param[@name='importLabel']"):
    child.attrib["a"] = "b"

tree.write("output.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error message. The main problem is that you use `==` instead of `=` in this line:

```
sub.attrib['value'] == "working"
```

---

The code can be simplified. If you want one specific element, just get it with `find()`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("path/file.xml")

param = tree.find(".//param")
if param.attrib['name'] == "importLabel":
    param.attrib['value'] = "working"

tree.write('output.xml')
```