# Recalculate XML child element

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

Using python3 I am trying to read an xml file and recalculate values based on the attributes within the Item, then write a copy of entire xml file with new values.

Example of xml file (about 10k rows in full file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item id="headscarf_d"
        name="{=wW3iouiU}Hijab"
        mesh="headscarf_d"
        culture="Culture.aserai"
        weight="0.5"
        value="63"
        appearance="1"
        Type="HeadArmor">
    <ItemComponent>
      <Armor head_armor="3"
             has_gender_variations="false"
             beard_cover_type="type3"
             hair_cover_type="all"
             modifier_group="cloth_unarmoured"
             material_type="Cloth"/>
    </ItemComponent>
    <Flags Civilian="true"
           UseTeamColor="true" />
  </Item>
  <Item id="open_head_scarf"
        name="{=qsVRoGUv}Open Head Scarf"
        mesh="aserai_helmet_c"
        culture="Culture.aserai"
        weight="0.6"
        value="174"
        appearance="1"
        Type="HeadArmor">
    <ItemComponent>
      <Armor head_armor="5"
             has_gender_variations="false"
             beard_cover_type="type3"
             hair_cover_type="all"
             modifier_group="cloth_unarmoured"
             material_type="Cloth"/>
    </ItemComponent>
    <Flags Civilian="true"
           UseTeamColor="true" />
  </Item>
  <Item id="woven_turban"
        name="{=ArPvuBYK}Woven Turban"
        subtype="head_armor"
        mesh="aserai_helmet_h"
        culture="Culture.aserai"
        weight="0.8"
        difficulty="0"
        value="250"
        appearance="1"
        Type="HeadArmor">
    <ItemComponent>
      <Armor head_armor="6"
             has_gender_variations="false"
             beard_cover_type="type2"
             hair_cover_type="all"
             modifier_group="cloth_unarmoured"
             material_type="Cloth"/>
    </ItemComponent>
    <Flags Civilian="true"
           UseTeamColor="true" />
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Taking a single item from the example xml,

```
<Item id="headscarf_d"
        name="{=wW3iouiU}Hijab"
        mesh="headscarf_d"
        culture="Culture.aserai"
        weight="0.5"
        value="63"
        appearance="1"
        Type="HeadArmor">
    <ItemComponent>
      <Armor head_armor="3"
             has_gender_variations="false"
             beard_cover_type="type3"
             hair_cover_type="all"
             modifier_group="cloth_unarmoured"
             material_type="Cloth"/>
    </ItemComponent>
    <Flags Civilian="true"
           UseTeamColor="true" />
```

For simplicity say I wanted to take the Item value (63 above example) and divide by 2 (63/2=31.5). Then if the Item's ItemComponent material_type="Cloth" divide by 2 again (31.5/2=15.75). Finally round to an integer before updating the value and repeating for each item then writing the new updated xml file.

I attempted to use [Reading, modifying and writing xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970696/reading-modifying-and-writing-xml) but could not get anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
from lxml import etree
import math

inv="""[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(inv)

values = doc.xpath('//Item')
materials  = doc.xpath('Item//ItemComponent//Armor')
for t, m in zip(values,materials):
    if m.attrib['material_type'] == 'Cloth':
        val = float(t.attrib['value'])/4
        t.attrib['value'] = str(math.ceil(val))
    else:
        t.attrib['value']= str(math.ceil(val*2))
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output is your xml with the `Items/Item/@value` attribute value divided by 2 or 4, as necessary, and rounded up by `math.ceil()`. Since all `Items` in your example have `cloth` as the value of the attribute `material_type`, they were all divided by 4 and rounded up to:

```
16
44
63
```

Comment: Works great, only thing I noticed is that the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> needed to be removed. Most appreciated!

Comment: @Exx Good to hear! If we're done, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, my only other question would be how to add the value attribute/tag if the Item attribute did not already did not have one.

Comment: @Exx I'm not really sure what you mean, but the best thing to do - also as per SO policy - is just to post it as another question. I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I'll take a shot myself first and make a follow-up question if needed.